# How to autowire HttpSessionManager Bean in spring?

Tags: spring-session

so I'm using the `spring-session` project and I want to know if it is possible to autowire the `HttpSessionManager` bean? I can see in the `users` example you are getting it from the request together with the `SessionRepository`:

```
    HttpSessionManager sessionManager =
            (HttpSessionManager) req.getAttribute(HttpSessionManager.class.getName());
    SessionRepository<Session> repo =
            (SessionRepository<Session>) req.getAttribute(SessionRepository.class.getName());
```

However, I want to access it from a service near the db layer and because I don't think it is a good design practice to pass the request down to the service I tried to autowire it but it doesn't find a bean of this type. The `SessionRepository` can be autowired fine because I have defined the bean in my configuration. I also tried to get it using the `RequestContextHolder` but then the `getSessionIds` methods always returns empty map, so I end up creating a new session all the time. Here's my whole method:

```
@Override
public Session getCurrentSession() {

    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();

    HttpSessionManager sessionManager =
        (HttpSessionManager) request.getAttribute(HttpSessionManager.class.getName());

    final Map<String, String> sessionIds = sessionManager.getSessionIds(request);

    if (sessionIds != null) {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : sessionIds.entrySet()) {
            final Session session = sessionRepository.getSession(e.getValue());
            if (session != null) {
                return session;
            }
        }
    }

    Session session = sessionRepository.createSession();

    sessionRepository.save(session);

    return session;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `RequestContextHolder` is capturing the `HttpServletRequest` before the `SessionRepositoryFilter` is invoked. That means that the request will not yet be wrapped.

By default the `EnableRedisHttpSession` configuration does not expose `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` as a Bean. This is necessary in order to allow users to override the `SessionStrategy` and supporting older versions of Spring (newer versions of Spring support `@Conditional`). If you wish to expose `CookieHttpSessionStrategy` as a Bean, then you can add the following to your configuration:

```
@Bean
public CookieHttpSessionStrategy sessionStragegy() {
    return new CookieHttpSessionStrategy();
}
```

After thinking about it some I may be able to expose it in future versions. I have created [gh-spring-session-75](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/75) to address it.

Comment: Hi Rob, I tried adding the session strategy as a bean, and now I can autowire it, but when I call `sessionStrategy.getRequestedSessionId(request);` with the request from `RequestContextHolder` it always returns null. I'm not sure if `RequestContetHolder` passes the cookies....

Comment: Hi Rob, the cookies are passed. The first request comes with some sessionID but because the server was restarted the repository has no session so I end up creating a new session using the repository (look at the last 3 lines of my method). However this new session is not saved on the cookie, so the next request the cookie session ID is the same and the repository again cannot find it and I create another session. Do you know how to set the newly created session on the `CookieHttpSessionStrategy`?